# Catch elements from Path

Tags: java, spring, redirect, model-view-controller, path

Hello im working on redirect values to other page i have a method post with selected values in HashMap and later send them with redirectAttributes.mergeAttributes. It's create me path with values but how to catche this values to Get method controller

```
 @GetMapping("/compare/{attrMap}")
    public String compareElements(@RequestParam String attrMap, Model model) {
        System.out.println(attrMap);

        //model.addAttribute("packets", packetService.getAllPackets());
        return "packet/compare";
}    


@PostMapping("/list")
public String postListElements(@ModelAttribute PacketWithChecksCollectionDto packetWithChecksCollectionDto, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
                List<PacketWithChecksDto> packetWithChecksDtos =
                        packetService
                                .getAllPackets()
                                .stream()
                                .map(p -> PacketWithChecksDto.builder().packetDto(p).build())
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());

                List<PacketWithChecksDto> packet = packetWithChecksCollectionDto.getPacketWithChecksDtos().stream().filter(x -> x.isChecked()).collect(Collectors.toList());
                Map<String, Object[]> attrmap = new HashMap<>();
                attrmap.put("true", packet.stream().map(x -> x.getPacketDto().getId()).toArray());
                attrmap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " " + Arrays.toString(v)));
                redirectAttributes.mergeAttributes(attrmap);
                return "redirect:/packet/compare/";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the Request Param you need to pass the actual name of the param either in the annotation or as variable name. You also have to remove the `{attrMap}` part from your mapping path, because this is used for path variables (`@PathVariable`) and not request params:

```
@GetMapping("/compare")
public String compareElements(@RequestParam("abc") String abc, Model model) {
    System.out.println(abc);
    return "packet/compare";
}
```

If you call it with `/compare?abc=xyz` you will get the result `xyz`.

If you want all parameters as `Map` you can use `@RequestParam Map<String, String> params`.

For more information read the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html).

Comment: OK but how i can use attrMap in my controller. I have a path http://localhost:8086/packet/compare?true=16%2C17, but if i want to show attrMap.toString() in controller nothing happens

Comment: you are switching `packet` and `compare`. you are defining your mapping for `/compare/{attrMap}`. So you have either to switch that or change your call to `/compare/packet`.

Comment: I dont understand, i have all this method in one controller("/packet"). Post packet/list send selected object to compare in this same controller packet/compare/{attrMap} i have a values of object in path "/packet/compare?true=16%2C17" - ID:16 and ID:17 and now i'm trying do something on this id's in controller but i dont have them when i want print or something do in controller

Comment: Do you want to get the request param `true=16%2C17`? If yes please edit your question to make this clear.

Comment: @user11042713 I think I misunderstood your question. I updated my answer. Hope it helps now.